# How to avoid RF signal loss in a conductive cage acting like a Faraday shield?

Tags: rf, signal-integrity, loss, faraday-cage

I have a standard chip antenna mounted on a large ground PCB plane.

[image]

The product is unfortunately encapsulated inside a relatively open (carbon-fiber) conductive cage.

Unfortunately, I see an obvious loss in the RF signal due to the Faraday cage principle.

How can I avoid such loss?

It would be difficult to put the antenna outside the cage. But would it make sense to have a wire or some conductive tape from the ground antenna plane to the cage itself or to "outside"?

Comment: Convert the antenna to a patch type and mount it externally.

Comment: Also, carbon-fiber sounds like a pretty ineffective faraday cage, and chances are it doesn't shield *that* much

Comment: How much loss do you see? Can you show us the conductive cage?

Answer (score 0):

Place the antenna immediately next to the Carbon Fiber (not even an air gap), and your loss will greatly reduce.

This answer may guide you.

[Why are many IR receivers in metal cages?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295629/why-are-many-ir-receivers-in-metal-cages/295689#295689)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Can you please describe the rationales behind your answer?